# How to hide elements from the Angular layout.html in some pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I'm using ui-router and a index.html as my layout, inside them I have this div which will append others pages, for example:

I have this HTML, which is my layout.html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
   <title> My layout.html </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav>
    I have this NAVBAR
  </nav>
  <div ui-view></div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

So, if I access the page 'posts', the Angular will append the code inside the posts.html in the `<div ui-view></div>`

Nothing unusual, right?

The question is.. i have a 404.html template file, which I don't want show the navbar. Is possible take off or hide the navbar if the page is the 404.html?

Answer (score 3):

I would create a controller for the navigation section.

```
.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.$state = $state;
})
```

Then hide the navigation when the current state is 404:

```
<nav ng-controller="NavCtrl" ng-hide="$state.current.name == '404'">
    I have this NAVBAR
</nav>
```

Comment: This works very well if only a single page needs to hide the navbar. In cases where several of them do, I would create multiple templates, one for pages with a navbar and one for pages with navbar.

Comment: not working.. the sidebar doesn't hide, could you explain better?

Comment: well.. i was trying to find out and the $state.current.name is always the navcontroller, if i take of the ng-controller will work.